# open and return fastercsv object with headers

Tags: ruby, fastercsv

I have a data sample like following

```
Ticker,Date/Time,Conseqhigher,Conseqlower,H,L,newHigh,newLow,Prevbarlow,Prevbarhigh,uptrend,dntrend,min15low,min15high
EUR.USD-IDEALPRO-CASH,2012-02-19 17:20,1,0,1.3208,1.3198,1,1,1.3183,1.3211,0,0,1.3139,1.3153
EUR.USD-IDEALPRO-CASH,2012-02-19 17:25,0,0,1.3209,1.3198,1,0,1.3198,1.3208,0,0,1.3139,1.3153
```

I am trying to use faster csv to open it and process it later.

```
require 'fastercsv'
def query()

return FasterCSV.read("c:\\temp\\test.csv")

end
```

The read method does not have any headers option. How can i fix it?

Comment: Just use `require 'csv'` if you are using Mac OS 1.9+. CSV in Ruby is FasterCSV now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the standard CSV library. It's FasterCSV plus support for Ruby 1.9's m17n encoding engine.

Back to your question, there is a `:headers` option to access each value by the headers.

The `#read` method will slurp the entire file:

```
CSV.read(CSV_FILE_PATH, :headers => true).each do |line|
  puts line['Ticker']
end
```

The `#foreach` method is the intended primary interface for reading:

```
CSV.foreach(CSV_FILE_PATH, :headers => true) do |line|
  puts line['Ticker']
end
```

Both methods will output:

```
EUR.USD-IDEALPRO-CASH
EUR.USD-IDEALPRO-CASH
```

See http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html.

Comment: +1 for mentioning slurping the file, and recommending using `foreach`. It's good to mention why slurping isn't the correct thing to do.